# default page is not showing in react-paginate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, redux-thunk, react-paginate

I am using react,redux ,axios ,redux-thunk with typescript to get the list of users. I have also implemented pagination with react-paginate.Everything is working fine but on refresh default page data is not shown i have to click any page number from pagination to get the data.I tried to set the data in useEffect with empty dependency ,still it's not working.
Here i am attaching my code:https://github.com/Khatri-Jinal/ReactReduxAxiosTs